# Uploading file to empty field using Parse.com, other data already set

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and using Javascript to try and insert an image into a blank field while other data has already been set but this isn't working, I'm not getting any errors or anything to guide me what to do. I have been following the documentation.

```
$("form#fileform").submit(function () {

    var fileUploadControl = $("#file")[0];
    if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
        var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
        var name = "photo.jpg";
        var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
        console.log(1);
    }

    parseFile.save().then(function () {
        var user = new Parse.Object("User");
        user.set("username", "test");
        user.set("avatar", parseFile);
        user.save();
    }, 

    function (error) {
        // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });

    return false;
});
```

There is already an account created with username 'test' but has the 'avatar' field empty, i want to insert the image into the blank 'avatar' field where username = 'test'. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, could somebody guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a Parse project few month ago, so I don't have anymore the docs in mind.

First, I'm not sure you have to use the `save` method on the `parseFile` object.
You can save your file directly with the user parse object.

Second, you set correctly a User parse object but I'm not sure that `user.set("username", "test")` querying the user with the username.
(may be it does if username is a unique key ?).

So I would recommend to get the user parse object by username, then set the parseFile object in it and `save`.
I did something like this in my project and it works.

```
new Parse.Query('User').equalTo('username', "test").first().then(function(user){
  user.set("avatar", parseFile);
  return user.save();
}, function(error) {
  // Get user failed
}).then((user) => {
  // Avatar saved !
}), function(error) {
  // ... or not
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, I'm getting a 'You cannot modify this user' error

Comment: Did you set some [roles](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Role.html) ? Or set others permissions like [ACL (CRUD)](http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-one-class-at-a-time/) ?

Comment: No, i'm very new to Parse, i'll look into it now